# How do I limit Input html date for year's field?

Tags: javascript, php

[input date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJMbv.png)

How do I limit the maximum length for the year's field?

Comment: you'll be better off using a jquery plugin or 3rd party datepicker plugin for this as type=date does not work on browsers such as Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it on the input `max='2018-01-01'`

Reference the link below https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp